# FireFox Web Extension native messaging Run exe aplication

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-native-messaging

I try make a Firefox extension call to native application exe on client with jpm (xpcom) and run success on debugging firefox but I can't verified or Signing on firefox addons and can't Install add-ons from file, too.
I recevied error from firefox: "Starting with Firefox 53, new extensions on this site can only be webextensions."

I Try again make a extension with webextionsions, but it not support xpcom, I can't call to exe application.

I hope, everyone can help me find solutions to call to exe application with webextensions

Comment: Did you read [Native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging)?

Comment: I read native messaging, but Firefox Native msg just call app *.bat and must be setup python environment. I want call *.exe app.

Comment: Given that the example shows calling a Python script, your belief that you can only run *.bat* files appears to be false. The example also shows using a *.bat* file to start the Python script (in case that is needed by Windows). You should be able to specify whatever type of executable you desire, as long as the OS reliably executes it.